DENEB VEGA - scrolling is frozing after change of signal using bind
Im beginner in Deneb Vega. I have created Gantt chart in which the user can change time unit observed. If he changes time unit from a daily to monthly, the width od x_band is decreased and the overall width of chart is changed. But scrollbar does not react on this change,  it  stayes frozen, and is not usable at all.  User does not have a chance to see hidden part of visual. Can someone help me, how to overcome this issue?[text]
Here is the link on .pbix>
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gzf8wkokuof9e6zp9rq0l/DENEB_GanttChart.pbix?rlkey=dhik6qfw5dzbm7lo9rzzujp1c&st=h6hgsd0r&dl=0
IN desktop when you click on scrollbar its alive, in service frozen at all.

Did you create that from scratch ;)

No , David you had to recognise that 70% of code is based on your Gantt chart published here> https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase/blob/main/Gantt%20Chart/Thumbnail.png    Im learning from the best :)

Thanks :). I'm not sure about your issue but I'm in the middle of rebuilding that Gantt to include the ability to zoom to different granularities and also pan and keep axes in view. Hopefully, it will be finished soon and you can use that. It is a rewrite from the ground up.

For sure I will study it, good luck.
